# Get element from HTML object javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a HTML String and I want to get img element and initialize it.

```
  var discountItem =  '<li class="sidebar-brand" style="font-weight: bold; color: #9999  class="col-item">' +
            '<div class="post-img-content">' +
                '<img src=" " class="img-responsive" id="mimo"  />'+
                '<span class="post-title">'+
                    '<b>Perfumes</b><br>'+
                    '<b>Clássico</b>'+
                '</span>'+
                '<span class="round-tag">-15%</span>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</li>';

        var k = app.clone(discountItem);


        var df = document.createDocumentFragment();

        // create a placeholder node to hold the innerHTML
        var el = document.createElement('body');
        el.innerHTML = k;

        // append to the document fragment
        df.appendChild(el);

        // execute .getElementById
        console.log(df.getElementByClassName('img-responsive');         

        view += k;

clone : function(obj){
    try{
        var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    } catch(ex){
        console.log("you are using an old navigator");
    }
    return copy;
}
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

My goal is to initialize the src of the image.
Could someone help me ?

Comment: The code presented has syntax errors. What's that entire bit at the end and how does it relate to your question?

Comment: I have a HTML string and I want to initialize one element of it.
I want to add a src to the img element.

Comment: Which...has nothing to do with my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find the `img` element, you can do a lot less work: Just create a `body`, append that HTML to it, and use `querySelector`:

```js
var discountItem =  '<li class="sidebar-brand" style="font-weight: bold; color: #9999  class="col-item">' +
            '<div class="post-img-content">' +
                '<img src=" " class="img-responsive" id="mimo"  />'+
                '<span class="post-title">'+
                    '<b>Perfumes</b><br>'+
                    '<b>Clássico</b>'+
                '</span>'+
                '<span class="round-tag">-15%</span>'+
            '</div>'+
            '</li>';
var body = document.createElement("body");
body.innerHTML = discountItem;
var img = body.querySelector(".img-responsive");
img.src = "source path here";
```